# A nonnegative, monotonically increasing polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials

I want to parametrize a class of functions as the following polynomial

$$
f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2 x^2 + \cdots + c_d x^d
$$
for $d\to \infty$.

What are the conditions on $c = (c_0, c_1, ..., c_d)$ such that  $f(x)$ is nonnegative and monotonically increasing for *all* $x$.

For instance, I know that $c_0 \geq 0$, or I can choose $x = 0$ and it won't be nonnegative anymore. But even setting conditions on $c_1$ seems not that obvious.

I also conjecture that $d$ finite will never work, since I can pick $x$ a very large negative number, and if $d$ is even then $f'(x)<0$, and if $d$ is odd then $f(x) < 0$.

An example of a polynomial that does work is if $c_k = \frac{t^k}{k!}$ for any positive $t$, since this leads to $f(x) = e^{tx}$. Are there others? Is it easy/possible to characterize?

Comment: You mean series, not polynomial : a  monotonic polynomial that isn't constant must  have odd degree, hence it won't be nonnegative.

Comment: Well I mean a series that is a function of $x$. Does polynomial always refer to finite degree? I agree that if we restrict $d$ to be finite, the goal is not achievable. What I am hoping to do is to parametrize all continuous functions in terms of an infinite sequence of $c_k$, and give conditions on $c_k$ to ensure monotonic increasing and nonnegative. The only explicit example I can think of is exponential, although of course we can draw many other examples.